# Find out parameters passed to a function

Tags: php, debugging

I'm trying to find out the name of the paramters that were passed to a function.

To do this I'm using debug_backtrace() to get the file and line from which the function was called.

Then open the file, read it line by line until the line that I'm looking for comes up.

```
$file = fopen($caller['file'], 'r' );
$line = 0;
while(($row = fgets($file)) !== false){
  $line++; 
  if($line == $caller['line']) break;
}      

fclose($file);

// $row is my line
```

So now i have a line like:

`my_function ($var1, some_other_function($othervar1, $othervar2));`

How can I extract arguments from it? I want to get an array like:

```
array('$var1', 'some_other_function($othervar1, $othervar2)');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a complicated issue.  Even in your example, the second parameter to the function doesn't have a name because it is the return value of a call to another function.

You may have some luck with [token_get_all()](http://php.net/token_get_all) to tokenize the code for you and then you can loop over the results and try to get what you need.

```
$tokens = token_get_all('<?php my_function($var1, some_other_function($othervar1, $othervar2)); ?>');

print_r($tokens);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 372
            [1] => <?php 
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 307
            [1] => my_function
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => (
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 309
            [1] => $var1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [4] => ,
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 375
            [1] =>  
            [2] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 307
            [1] => some_other_function
            [2] => 1
        )

    [7] => (
    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 309
            [1] => $othervar1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [9] => ,
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 375
            [1] =>  
            [2] => 1
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 309
            [1] => $othervar2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [12] => )
    [13] => )
    [14] => ;
    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 375
            [1] =>  
            [2] => 1
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 374
            [1] => ?>
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

Using the [List of Parser Tokens](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) you can loop over that array and figure out what the parameters passed to the function were.  Even so, it may be too generic because your call to `my_function` is just a `T_STRING` token that the Zend Engine eventually looks for in a function table and calls the function if it exists, or throws a fatal error if it doesn't.

Comment: This.  About the only way you're gonna get what you're looking for is to parse the PHP code yourself.  (By the time the function is called, PHP has pretty much forgotten where the values originally came from...so there's no way it can give you '$var1' or 'some_other_function($othervar1, $othervar2)'.  The best it can ever do is give you the values.)

Comment: its not true, it works!! :D It even gives me line numbers so I don't need to read the file myself anymore. So I iterated trough all tokens and set a few "state" variables to determine if I'm in the right position, and extracted the arguments from the token data :) thanks

Comment: @Alex Nice I wouldn't mind seeing some of the code if you don't mind posting it.  You can edit my answer or add it to your question, only if you feel like sharing of course.  Either way, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for get_func_args: http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `func_get_args`. You can use it to get an array of all values passed in to a function like so:

```
<?php

$args = func_get_args();
var_export($args);

?>
```

You *can not* retrieve the names of the values a function accepts in PHP.

The reasoning behind this is simple, you will never rearrange the order of your input variables. Think of this:

```
function foo($var1, $var2, $var3) {
```

You pass in what you want for `$var1` in as parameter 1. You will never pass what you want for `$var1` in parameter 2 or 3.

Why don't your just log your function parameters inside the function itself?

```
function foo($one, $two) {
    echo '$one: '. $one "\n";
    echo '$two: '. $two "\n";
}
```

Comment: You define the names when you define the function. Out of curiosity, why do you need the names?

Comment: You can not get the name of the variables a function takes in with PHP.

Comment: The parameters for your function _never_ change. I think what you are looking to do is print the variables themselves within the function to see if they are passed correctly.

Comment: no, I'm just trying to code a nice debug function, and I`ll like to also print info about the source

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
function my_func ($var, $callback) {
   $args = func_get_args();
   call_user_func($callback);
   ...
}
```

and:

```
my_func('value1', 'some_other_function');
```

then:

$args will be ('value', 'some_other_function');

Comment: if you call some_other_function on parameters, you can not retrieve the function name

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method to a specific line from a file is to read it using `file`, though this might cause some performance overhead since it will read the whole file at once:

```
function func ($arg1, $arg2) 
{
  list($caller) = debug_backtrace (); 
  $file_lines   = file ($caller['file']);

  echo "function called as: " . $file_lines[$caller['line'] - 1]; 
}

$a = $b = 0;

func ($a,$b);
```

```
function called as: func ($a,$b);
```

---

There are a few issues with doing what you are doing though, for one you assume that the contents of where the calling takes place only spans across one line. If you are having lots of arguments to a function you might split it up onto several lines as in the below snippet, in which case your function won't behave as it should.

```
func (
  $a, $b,
  $c, $d
);
```

<sup>The contents printed by your function will only contain `);`</sup>

---

*pending edit with a full-blown example that will "always" work*

Comment: you're right about the multi-line thing. I was thinking I could read all lines until my line comes up, then do a substr() from the last occurence of `my _function` name until the end. That should fix this:P

Comment: @Alex not really though, it's a thought but it won't be guaranteed to work.. I'll update my post soon, writing a parser that just got pretty advanced, think you'll like it! ;)

Comment: @Alex got a working snippet, just going to clean up the code to make it readable..

Comment: @refp still waiting on this example that will "always" work... :)

Comment: @cHao I work as a fashion model and was sent abroad, therefore I haven't been able to get on stackoverflow - but I will update the answer in a couple of days, code is written and I have it stored on my server at home.

Comment: @cHao and I'm still abroad doing modelling work, currently in NYC will be sent to London in a few days. work before pleasure, money before PoC's ;)